# Wrong pop-up position when using twitter-bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Popup don't show at center of screen when the width was big, such as 900px.

Everyone can view example here and using firebug to edit the width of pop-up, after that, It will wrong display.

http://www.w3resource.com/twitter-bootstrap/modal-example.html#

Answer (score 0):

80% width, centered, responsive using only CSS:

```
#modal {    
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: -40%;
    left: 50%;
}
```

https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/675